# Extract DB from accidentally formatted /data

Tags: sms, clockworkmod-recovery, data-recovery, formatting, ext4

I had to factory reset my Samsung Galaxy Note i717 (1stGen AT&T), and I forgot to backup before formatting /data.

I need to extract the messages DB from it, because I have many important messages from my phone that I require.

So far, I have (after rebooting into CWM):

```
$ adb shell mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p26 on /cache type ext4 (rw,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1 on /external_sd type vfat (rw,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p28 on /sdcard type vfat (rw,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p25 on /data type ext4 (rw,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

Then I unmounted data from CWM, and then:

```
$ adb shell dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p25 of=/external_sd/data.backup bs=4M
512+1 records in
512+1 records out
2149580800 bytes (2.0GB) copied, 226.108215 seconds, 9.1MB/s

$ adb shell ls -l /external_sd
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root         16384 Mar 18  2013 2
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root         16384 Apr 20  2013 Android
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root         16384 Dec 14  2012 DCIM
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root         16384 Mar 20  2013 DriveDroid
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root         16384 Dec  5  2012 LOST.DIR
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root        360448 May  1  2013 TitaniumBackup
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root         16384 Dec 16  2012 clockworkmod
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root     173194344 Apr 25  2013 cm-10.1-20130411-EXPERIMENTAL-quincyatt-M3.zip
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root         16384 Dec  5  2012 data
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root     2149580800 Nov 14 10:43 data.backup
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root         16384 Dec 22  2012 media
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        102400 Apr  8  2013 mmssms.db
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root       7686144 Feb 16  2013 recovery.img
```

Next I DL'ed the backup file to my computer:

```
$ adb pull /external_sd/data.backup
8224 KB/s (2149580800 bytes in 255.223s)

$ ls -l
total 2099204
-rw-r--r-- 1 haneefmubarak haneefmubarak 2149580800 Nov 14 02:56 data.backup
```

So now what I have is an image of my /data partition (ext4). How can I file-carve for the messages (SMS) DB file? I have a nandroid copy from a while back that has some of my old messages (I set my SMS to never delete), would that help?

```
Model: SGH-I717
Manu.: Samsung
Carrier: AT&T
ROM: CM 10.2
AOSP: v4.2 Jelly Bean
code: quincyatt
```

Comment: I recommend you taking a look into our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info), which explicitly mentions file carving and gives a few references.

Comment: @Izzy Well, this question isn't about how to generically file-carve, but rather on how to file-carve for Android DB files, especially Android SMS DBs.